# Is it possible to disable AAD Auth on specific Azure functions?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

**Background:** I have an Azure Function App deployed with App Service Authentication (easyauth) enabled using AAD, hooked up to an Azure AD B2C tenant. It's all working great and as expected. That said I have encountered a new scenario that I'd like to support **with the same function app** but without the auth turned on. Specifically I'd like one specific function to be called anonymously (perhaps even behind a function proxy).

**Question:** Is it possible to disable auth on a specific function in the same function app where everything else has authentication enforced?

I've played around with the idea of changing the "*Action to take when request is not authenticated*" to "*Allow Anonymous request (no action)*" however that then leaves me with the task of somehow in every other function that requires auth, doing *something* that would ensure that a request is in fact authenticated. Note that I have no idea what the *something* is that I'd have to do yet in this case.

Worst case I'll setup a totally separate function app that only exposes the single function that I need to call anonymously... however it feels like there should be a better solution that doesn't require me sharing source across two projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE: Removed reference to the URL Authorization Rules preview feature, which was discontinued. New information provided below.**

You can enable anonymous access to individual URLs using the `globalValidation.excludedPaths` ARM setting for Easy Auth. Any path in this array will NOT have the global authorization rules checked, so use it carefully.

Example:

```json
{
    "globalValidation": {
        "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RejectWith401",
        "redirectToProvider": "aad",
        "excludedPaths": [
            "/api/MyAnonymousHttpTriggerFunction"
        ]
    },
}
```

I don't believe the portal or CLI support has been enabled for this quite yet, but you should be able to set this up in ARM directly under `Microsoft.Web/sites/<siteName>/config/authsettingsV2`. If you want to manually test it out, I recommend setting up an app and updating these settings using [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com).

If you're using file-based configuration (advanced), the same JSON settings apply and you can find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-file-based#configuration-file-reference).

Comment: This worked flawlessly and solved my exact problem thank you. Will it one day support regex instead of a simple wildcard for the path_prefix?

Comment: We hadn't planned on it but we certainly could add it given the right level of interest.

Comment: Link appears to be dead. Here is where it migrated I think: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/11/17/URL-Authorization-Rules.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that they have deprecated this functionality and removed all documentation and blog posts about it :'( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/500371/azure-functions-url-authorization-rules.html

Comment: I've updated the answer with new information. The previous solution is no longer supported.

Comment: This actually works. Life saver!

Comment: Thank you! I've been hardly researching about this and I could not find documentation about this before your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can also add an App Setting `WEBSITE_WARMUP_PATH` pointing to the relative path of the function url in the function app. For e.g. `/api/MyAnonymousHttpTriggerFunction` and this path will not be considered for authentication.

This setting also supports multiple relative paths separated by `,` as a delimiter. For e.g.

`/api/MyAnonymousHttpTriggerFunction1,/api/MyAnonymousHttpTriggerFunction2`

More details about this setting is documented below:

https://github.com/cgillum/easyauth/wiki/Advanced-Application-Settings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-file-based#configuration-file-reference