# Azure URL authorization rules not being applied

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I want to enable Authentication/Authorization on a web app for all pages but one. I have a metadata page that I want to remain public while the rest of the app requires authentication.

Based on many other [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920079/allowing-public-access-to-only-1-endpoint-of-azure-application/57313377#57313377) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712457/is-it-possible-to-disable-aad-auth-on-specific-azure-functions?rq=1) and [blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/02/06/azure-traffic-manager-probe-degraded-due-to-401-from-azure-web-app/), I have enabled Authentication/Authorization on the app and set 'Action to take when request is not authenticated' to 'Allow Anonymous requests (no action).' I created an authorization.json file and put it in the site root:

```
{
    "routes": 
    [{
        "path_prefix": "/",
        "policies": 
        {
            "unauthenticated_action": "RedirectToLoginPage" 
        }
    },{
        "path_prefix": "/metadata",
        "policies": 
        { 
            "unauthenticated_action": "AllowAnonymous" 
        }
    }]
}
```

I expected that with this setup, unauthenticated requests to the base site and all pages except `/metadata` would require login. However, I am not redirected to login from any page. I have ensured I am logged out of Azure and using a private session, but I can still get right in.
As an experiment, I changed the authentication setting to redirect unauthenticated requests to AD login, and all pages redirected to login, as expected, but this does break other functionality since the `/metadata` page is protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but EasyAuth just would not work with my app. I tried rearranging file and URL structures, placing authorization.json at different places in the file tree... nothing worked. I eventually started looking for other solutions.
What I landed on was OpenID Connect v2 using the Microsoft Identity platform. Repo and tutorials [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg). Using this, you can decorate classes or methods with `Authorize` or `AllowAnonymous` attributes to define authorization behavior.
It was certainly more effort (and banging head against wall) to get this working, but it is working, so that's cool. I also believe this setup will allow me to apply role-based restrictions, which is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

As the [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920079/allowing-public-access-to-only-1-endpoint-of-azure-application/57313377#57313377) you provided, set `authorization.json` under `wwwroot` and set webapp  `Action to take when request is not authenticated` as `Allow Anonymous requests (no action)` then **restart webapp** will work fine.

**Note: Remember to restart your app service to make changes effective.**

Comment: I have done all of those. 
I have restarted several times. I have also fully stopped the app and started it back up.

Comment: It's odd. I test in my site and get the same result with you then I restart app and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem aswell, for me the reason was apparently that I had placed authorization.json in the websites wwwroot folder, not the wwwroot folder created by Azure. If anyone else is stuck with this issue, please make sure that you have placed the json file in the right folder:
[image]